# Codeigniter database delete and insert multiple records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem slightly different to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399799/delete-and-insert-multiple-records-in-database-using-codeigniter) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078616/codeigniter-deleting-multiple-records-in-checkbox). In my model class I had to separate the delete and save into two different functions as follows.

```
  #save advanced preferences
function savePreference($preferences){

    $this->db->insert('bingo_advanced_preferences', $preferences);  
    echo $this->db->last_query();   

}

 #delete advanced preferences
function deletePreference($user_id,$criteria){
return $this->db->delete('bingo_advanced_preferences', array('bingo_user_id' => $user_id,'adv_criteria' =>$criteria));

}
```

if I call these functions from the controller like this delete, update works.

```
 //language preferences


            if($this->input->post('language') && count($this->input->post('language')) > 0):
                $this->Bingo_advanced_preferences->deletePreference($user,'15');
                for ($i=0; $i < count($this->input->post('language')); $i++) { 
                    $language_options = array(
                    'bingo_user_id' => $user,
                    'adv_criteria' => 15, //languages
                    'adv_criteria_value' => $this->input->post('language')[$i],
                    'adv_date_created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                    );
                $this->Bingo_advanced_preferences->savePreference($language_options);
                }
            endif;
```

However this doesn't cater for a scenario where somebody deselects everything so the correct order should be like this.

```
    $this->Bingo_advanced_preferences->deletePreference($user,'15'); 

    if($this->input->post('language') && count($this->input->post('language')) > 0):

            for ($i=0; $i < count($this->input->post('language')); $i++) { 
                $language_options = array(
                'bingo_user_id' => $user,
                'adv_criteria' => 15, //languages
                'adv_criteria_value' => $this->input->post('language')[$i],
                'adv_date_created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                );
            $this->Bingo_advanced_preferences->savePreference($language_options);
            }
        endif;
```

This only deletes all the records with adv_criteria=15 and never updates(do the subsequent saving). Of course I have solved my problem with an if else statement so my question is why this doesn't work? How can we make this work?

Comment: I didn't understand this part from the last paragraph - "This only deletes all the records and never updates".

Comment: I have clarified the question

Comment: Okay let me try, if nothing is selected then, there is nothing to save subsequently. if something is selected i don't see any issue with subsequent saving. so everything looks good to me :o correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: The second arrangement will not save even if there is something selected which does not make sense

Comment: Well the code seems fine! it should work in ideal scenario, check if there is any error. i don't seem to catch anything. The code fail might happen only if the data being saved is dependent on the data which was deleted from the db. it doesn't seem like it does in the above code.

Comment: Ok let me check again

Comment: I still have this problem. I am now confused!

Comment: well everyone still reading this question an down-voting I advise you to reconsider your decision to use codeigniter in 2019 . When was the production version last supported

Answer (score 1):

For Delete , You can do this on view file like

```
<input type='checkbox' name='tableId[]' value='<?php echo $value->tableId; ?>"'>
```

Then on controller like this

```
function delete_multiple() {
    // Retrive Multiple Id List From Form
    $check_id = $this->input->post('tableId[]');

       // Multiple Delete Loop For Id
       foreach($check_id as $checkId) {
          $this->db->where('tableId', $checkId);
          $this->db->delete('TableName');
        }
}
```

For Insert , you can do this on view file same as above
Then on controller like this

```
function multiple_add() {
  $table_Id = $this->input->post('tableId[]');

  foreach($table_Id as $tableId) {

    $data_some = array(
    'tableId' => $tableId,
    'blah' => $this->input->post('blah')
    );

    // Insert Data Function Call
    $this->db->insert('TableName', $data_some);
    }
}
```

Comment: no queries in controller! it is a "Controller" not a "Model". First get the basics right .